# Draw NSString without using drawAtPoint or drawRectIn

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, subclass, drawrect

I have subclassed an UILabel and i use drawrect method to draw the string on the screen. This is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect   aRect  = self.frame;
    NSMutableArray *Text=[globaltextarray Text];

   [[NSString stringWithCString:[[Text objectAtIndex:labelindexpath.row] cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]  drawInRect:aRect
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:15.0] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
   [super drawRect:rect];     
}
```

It is working fine but it is slow for my purpose. I need to draw the string without using `[Label setNeedDisplay];` because setNeedsDisplay needs to be called from the main thread. The rendering work needs to be done in a background queue. I would be grateful if you could provide me with a small example. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new **CGContext** to draw the string into CGImage/UIImage using **CGBitmapContextCreateImage** on separate thread, then draw the bitmap(generated image) into view on the main thread.

**EDIT:**
Check this [post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/drawing-on-uiimages/) for example.

Comment: i tried the example but when i draw the generated image to the main thread is way too laggy than before with setNeedsDisplay! Am i missing something?

Comment: I think there's a wrong answer, this way doesn't shorten the time required for appearance. The first thing you should use the Instruments Time Profiler to find cause of slow program.

Comment: I did that already it is the drawrect in my subclassed UILabel that causes the laggy scroll!

Comment: in a UITableView? why not subclass UITableViewCell and drawing string directly?

Comment: Yes in an UITableView. Well i have thought of that but i have to change a lot of code...